# How can I get approved for a store credit card?

Tags: credit-card, credit, credit-history

How is a person supposed to get approved for a store credit card if they have insufficient credit history?

I just received a secured Visa card, but am wondering how long it will take to establish a credit history that will allow me to get approved for a store credit card, in order to raise my credit score by using more than just one credit card?

Comment: Welcome.  The answer is time.  Use your secured card correctly and graduate to a better credit score.  Is there a reason why you want a store card?  Also, please tag your question with your country.

Comment: If you are in the US I suggest you look at http://creditkarma.com it should help you understand your score and how to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that mere having more than one card will speed up the process of your credit score accumulation. Moreover, additional inquiries and new accounts actually reduce your credit score, albeit temporarily. So if you're talking short-term (less than a year) then adding another account not only be unneeded, it will actually be harmful. After a year having your secured credit card and managing it properly will bring you to the level you want to be to be approved for unsecured revolving credit.